# Relevantness synonym

Tags: synonyms

What need to use a word with a meaning of *relevantness*. Noun from the word *relevant*. I know that *relevantness* is not good. What do you suggest to use?

Comment: Hi wair, look up *relevant* in one or two dictionaries. You will found the related noun there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is available—and petty much unmistakable—in any reputable English dictionary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can someone explain when to use "relevance" and when "relevancy"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/230461/can-someone-explain-when-to-use-relevance-and-when-relevancy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form you are looking for is either [relevance](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/relevancy) or [relevancy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/relevancy):

> noun 1. the condition of being relevant, or connected with the matter at hand:
> *Some traditional institutions of the media lack relevance in this digital age.* - [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/relevancy)

On the difference between the two forms:

> **Relevance vs. relevancy**
>
> There is no difference between relevance and relevancy. Though the latter is the older form, relevance is now preferred in all varieties of English. In this century, relevance is about ten times as common as relevancy in U.S. popular usage, and the gap is even wider in British, Australian, and Canadian sources. - [grammarist.com](http://grammarist.com/usage/relevance-relevancy/)

As far as synonyms go, there is a large number of them available here:

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/relevance

You will find that some have more pertinence, aptness, appropriateness or dare I say relevance than others.